# Update gui to child winform from parent winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, delegates, invoke

What I’m trying to do, when we click on button in radform1(Parent), hide radform1 then update the text/label/radgrid header text values in Form1(child form),
 once we close the Form1(child form)..close radform1(Parent) as well.

I'm getting a error message : `Invalid OPeration Exception was Un-Handled`Cross-thread operation not valid
 Control 'radPageView1 has been accessed from a thread other than the one on which it was created.

How can i use the invoke or action method to fix this problem?? I couldn't understand the concept exactly.. Please explain to me what should i do here...Any help is appreciated!

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
        private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // French Version Button
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            radProgressBar1.Visible = true;
            frm.radGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Test"; // Change the Radgrid Header Text at Col[0]

        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ticks++;
            radProgressBar1.Value1 = ticks;
            if (ticks != 100) return;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            ticks = 0;

            frm.FormClosed += (_, args) => frm.Close();
            frm.Hide();
            frm.Show();

        }
```

Comment: If your using Windows.Form.Timer class, then cross thread shouldnt be a problem. Any ways, for cross thread issue you can use this.Invoke(delegate...) or this.Invoke(MethodInvoker).

Also note that, as soon as you say Timer.Enabled, then the timer immediately starts in background.

Comment: @zenwalker: Could you please show me, how do i update usinf the method ovoker in my gui. Please explain to me with some code for my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Just used Windows Forms TImer class and i am just updating the textbox text value. Not used any Invokers. http://pastebin.com/hbnX9xgC Hope it gives you some hint.

Also please note the draw back of using Windows Forms Timer is that, it runs along with the UI thread. So if the UI thread becomes unresponsive, then your timer is inefficient and not accurate.

Comment: @zenwalker: Then what is the best solution?? From your code, what i understood is to update gui in the same window using timer. I guess u know, i want to update gui from another window. Probably I don't undersatnd it.

Comment: Hope this helps if i understood your qs properly. Again using the same timer type, but this time i have added a new Form Form2 which has a public member (TextBox). On button click, i am sending the value to its textbox component for displaying. Just fiddle with the code and youll get it http://pastebin.com/KvMXjJm6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand well, but I think you need something like this:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Form c, Action<Form> action)
        {
            if (c.InvokeRequired)
            {
                try { c.Invoke(new Action(() => action(c))); }
                catch { }
            }
            else
            {
                action(c);
            }
        }
```

and call

```
frm.InvokeIfRequired((_)=>{frm.ChangeSomethingInTheUI();});
```

in this way you are sure that the action will be performed inside the right thread.

Hope this helps.